# How to import the Login component provided by ra-ui-materialui of the new react-admin

Tags: admin-on-rest, react-admin

I want to use the [Login component](https://github.com/marmelab/admin-on-rest/blob/next/packages/ra-ui-materialui/src/auth/Login.js) provided by the ra-ui-materialui inside the [next version of admin-on-rest](https://github.com/marmelab/admin-on-rest/blob/next/UPGRADE.md).

I tried

```
import { Login } from 'ra-ui-materialui'
import { Login } from 'react-admin/ra-ui-materialui'
import { Login } from 'react-admin/ra-ui-materialui/auth'
import { Login } from 'react-admin/packages/ra-ui-materialui/src/auth'
import Login from 'react-admin/packages/ra-ui-materialui/src/auth'
```

They all resulted into an compile error:

> Module not found: Can't resolve 'ra-ui-materialui' in '/my-app/src'

or

> Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-admin/ra-ui-materialui' in '/my-app/src'

etc.

How can I import the provided [Login component](https://github.com/marmelab/admin-on-rest/blob/next/packages/ra-ui-materialui/src/auth/Login.js) and use it in my react-admin app?

*PS: For the time being, I've added the admin-on-rest tag too as this is the first question that concerns react-admin. For the purpose of this question and maybe many more to come, I created the [tag react-admin](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/react-admin/info).*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assumed that the [local packages of react-admin](https://github.com/marmelab/admin-on-rest/tree/next/packages) would be available automatically just by the earlier installation of react-admin that I did. I was wrong. You need to yarn add that separately.

So, next to:

`yarn add react-admin`

You also need to:

`yarn add ra-ui-materialui`

And then this works:

`import { Login } from 'ra-ui-materialui'`

Comment: Correct, I do not see any more activity on 'next' for the last 5 days (and on 'master' for the last 3 days) and I am worried about the project.

Comment: I see a lot of indicators telling me to trust in their effort. Don't worry. Contribute! Btw I migrated an app from admin-on-rest to react-admin went smoothly and took me an hour. Checkout UPGRADE.md in the `next` branch

Comment: Thanks Christiaan, did 'dependentInput' also work?

Also, I have these issues:
https://github.com/marmelab/admin-on-rest/issues/1603
https://github.com/marmelab/admin-on-rest/issues/1602

Do you want to ask them as separate stackoverflow questions? I am not sure if they are bugs or I do something wrong.